# Generic App service Interface with multiple implementations

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to implement a generic service interface into multiple classes. Is this possible to do? Seems that it just picks one of the classes to inject into. I'm likely missing something with the dependency injection itself. I would like to stay away from creating a separate interface for each class if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have an interface like that:

`public interface IMyService<TEntity> { ... }`

and you have 2 implementations:

`public class MyUserService : IMyService<User> { ... }
public class MyRoleService : IMyService<Role> { ... }`

To be able to inject `IMyService<User>` or `IMyService<Role>` you should register them to DI in your module's Initialize method:

`IocManager.Register<IMyService<User>, MyUserService>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);`
`IocManager.Register<IMyService<Role>, MyRoleService>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);`

Comment: Thanks i believe you answered my questions properly, however i'm using ASP boilerplate and its doing some behind the scenes DI that i am totally not sure how it all works. I think i would have to do some additional work to make it work or override some of the things it is doing.

Comment: Sure, I know that you're using the ABP framework. I'm the lead contributor of the framework and I know what it does behind the scenes :) So, try my suggestion first, the we see how it works.

Comment: my application is a little out of the norm, the classes return a dataset so there is no concrete types being used at all or needed to be injected. I was also trying to utilize the dynamic controllers by placing my app services in the application project and letting it build the controller dynamically. One solution i found to work is to create a generic app service that i DI to be the default then inject the iocresolver and then invoke the function for each and combine the result sets together and then return that. I will admit i don't know DI very well so this may be bad practice.